# setTimeout not working properly if i pass key prop to maped element

Tags: reactjs

Here is my notification component.

Notification.js

```
const Notification = (props) => {
  const [dNone, setdNone] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      setdNone(true);
    }, 4000);
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    // type
    // 1 : error-alert
    // 2 : warning-alert
    // 3 : info-alert
    // 4 : success-alert
    <div className={`custom-alert ${props.type} ${dNone ? "d-none" : ""}`}>
      <span className="bi bi-x-circle-fill error-icon-alert"></span>
      <div>
        <p className="mb-0 pb-0 custom-alert-desc">{props.msg}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

UseNotificationManager.js

```
function UseNotificationManager(List, type) {
  return List.map((item) => {
    return <Notification type={type} msg={item.msg} />;
  });
}
```

here List is a list of the message strings.

This work fine, the notification is removed after 4 seconds, if there is more than 1 message there will be two notification and they will be removed in the manner they were added. when I add a new notification only a new message will be added to the existing notification that is not removed yet.

Problem is when i pass key prop in 
all the notification is removed at once and when I add a new notification it also displays all old message with new one and all are removed at the same time.

I don't know why that is happening.

I expect that if I add a notification it displayed when I add a second notification after a 3-second message is added to the existing one. The first notification should disappear after 3+1 = 4 seconds even If I pass the key prop to .

here is the reproducible code.
https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-bird-nk0oj0?file=/src/UseNotificationManager.js:230-243

Comment: Where in the code shown are you "passing a key prop"?  Please provide a runnable [mcve] demonstrating the problem and indicate the specific problem you are observing in that example.

Comment: @Devid I have added the link for a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CodeSandbox example passes in a `key` that changes for every render, causing React to *always* unmount and remount the component. That's arguably *worse* than passing in no key. The key should be specific to the item rendered, and not change.

In other words, generate an unique ID for the data, e.g.

```
setNotificationList((prev) => [
  ...prev,
  { id: uuid(), msg: "Something went wrong..........!" }
]);
```

and use it as the key when rendering notifications (I renamed the component here since the convention is that things that start with `use` are hooks):

```
function NotificationManager(notificationList, type) {
  return notificationList.map((item) => {
    return <Notification type={type} key={item.id} msg={item.msg} />;
  });
}
```